# How to rename group values into ordered values without reordering total data frame?

Tags: r

In a large datafile I need to rename grouping variables into an ordered number. Is there an easy way to do that?

This is an example of what I want to do:

```
  group value
1     3     1
2     3     2
3     3     3
4     1     4
5     1     5
6     1     6
7     2     7
8     2     8
9     2     9
```

This data frame I want to change into (by renaming the group variable):

```
  group value
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     1     3
4     2     4
5     2     5
6     2     6
7     3     7
8     3     8
9     3     9
```

So, I want to rename the group value with ordered numbers, without reordering the total data frame. 
Has anyone have an idea about how to do this?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `factor`

```
df1$group <- as.numeric(factor(df1$group, levels=unique(df1$group)))
```